# How do we get user input in java script console

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio, input, prompt

In Python I used input function to get user input but in javascript I am trying to use prompt()
which I seen in goolgle search but it is not working. I am using visual studio code editor.
the code is something like that,

```
let name = prompt('what is your name')
console.log(name + 'is your name')
```

Comment: Are you using NodeJS or the Chrome DevTools? prompt is a web browser spec, and will only work in a web browser.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NodeJS, to prompt for user input, you can use the `readline` module.

Here is an example of how you can prompt the user for their name and then greet them:

```js
const readline = require('readline');

const rl = readline.createInterface({
  input: process.stdin,
  output: process.stdout
});

rl.question('What is your name? ', (name) => {
  console.log(`Hello, ${name}!`);
  rl.close();
});
```

More info: https://nodejs.org/api/readline.html.